# Maps that preserve the group product, but not necessarily the identity

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

I am interested in the following problem: given a finite group $G$, and elements $a, b, c, d \in G$, what are the functions $f:G \to G$ such that $f(a) \cdot f(b) = f(c) \cdot f(d)$ if $a \cdot b = c \cdot d$? Here, $\cdot$ is the product in the group, and note that I do not require the identity element to be preserved under the function $f$. Essentially, I am asking how much freedom I have to relabel the elements of the group without changing the product of two elements.

I have worked through all of the finite groups of order 5 or less, but I was wondering if there were general results beyond that point, such as when the group in question is non-abelian. The maps $f$ should be in the symmetric group acting on $|G|$ elements, but how does the subgroup of $S_{|G|}$ depend on the choice of $G$?

Comment: If the products are equal then the function values will also be, simply be virtue of it being a function.

Comment: Did you mean to have $f(a\cdot b) = f(c)\cdot f(d)$ perhaps?

Comment: Hi Tobias -- yes, you're right, I didn't mean what I originally wrote! I have edited the original post to reflect that.

Comment: Right, but there are additional maps as well. For example, in $Z_2$, the map $f(0) \to 1, f(1) \to 0$ meets the condition above, but does not preserve the identity in $Z_2$.

Comment: Actually, I misread the condition. I will need to think about the given one.